select2 y selectpicker no funcionan dentro de una tabla HTML
tengo un SELECT dentro de una celda html,
si aplico  Select2 ó Selecpicker no hacen efecto.
Si lo aplico a cualquier SELECT fuera de la tabla, no hay problema.
tengo esto:
En el "Ready":
$(".prueba").select2();

Contenido de la tabla:
var contenido = '<tr>'+
        '<td>' +"<img class='borrar' src='imagenes/Icos/papelera1.png' width=15 height=15 />" +'</td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:right">' + '</td>'+
        '<td>' +'<select id="uds" class="form-control" id="'+prd1+'">'+
        '<option value=0>Elegir U.medida</option><option value=1>Uds.</option><option value=2>KG.</option><option value=3> Lt.</option>'+'</select>'+ '</td>'+
       '<td >' +"<select class='prueba'   id="+prd+" onchange='ponerarticulo(this.value)'>"+'<option value=0>Elegir Producto</option>' +'</select>' + '</td>'+
        '<td style="text-align:right">' + '</td>'+
        '</tr>';

Esto pasa si el SELECT está fuera de la tabla:
!!! tengo buscador...!!!

Esto, si el SELECT está dentro de la tabla.
Nada de nada

alguna sugerencia ??.
Gracias de nuevo...

Hola Aldeano, pareciera que la filas las creas dinámicamente, de ser así, es lógico que el select2 no se cree sobre en esa fila ya que la misma no existía al momento de ejecutar el comando. ¿Podes actualizar tu pregunta agregando la función que crea las filas?

hago la asignación después de crear la linea y todo correcto...gracias por la sugerencia..

Hola Aldeano, si solucionaste tu problema, recordá que podes responder a tu propia pregunta. Detalla dónde estaba el error y como lo solucionaste, también incluí el código al que llegaste. Saludos!

yo tengo el mismo incombeniente. el select se carga primero despues llamo a la funcion y no carga. cuando hago el segundo llamado a la pagina desde php si me funciona.

La sugerencia de Marcos me llevó a la solución del problema y efectivamente asignando 'select2' después de agregar los datos...no antes....
$('#tabla tbody').append(contenido);
$(".prueba").select2();

debería haber considerado que hay vida despues de '$( document ).ready'...
Gracias a todos por estar ahí...
